# Multiple Build definitions in VSTS 2008 help needed

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, tfvc

I was wondering if the following can be done in VSTS 2008.

I have a main branch and several branches where many code change will be going on. Is there a way to build a required branch on demand?

Also I have many labeled versions of code and a main branch, is there a way to build a labeled version of the code on demand?

Answer (score 0):

TFS doesn't support this out of the box.
I've done something similar where I created a build definition that read an XML file for what it was to build and deploy and then it perfomred the necessary actions to complete that. It sounds like you would need a similar thing.

Comment: You mean to say, I ll maintain an XML file where I define which version of the Build should be considered and while building, read from the xml file and build that version is it...?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. In my case I have the Team Build to run a file named Deploy.proj in a known location, this file will inspect an xml file DeployManifest.xml which contains the name of applications to deploy and the source root for those applications. The source root is necessary becuase you may want to deploy a specific branch.